# Why is my decryption function not working with CryptoJS?

Tags: javascript, php, react-native, encryption

I´m pretty new to encryption and I was trying out CryptoJS with AES for a ReactNative project. The requierment is to fetch data from an end point with encrypted data, but when I try to decrypt my code returns an empty string.

The end point data is encrypted by this functions in PHP:

```
    $KEY;
    $IV_LENGTH = 16;
```

Here the key is static and already generated by **getKey()** function.

```
    public function encrypt($plain_text){
        global $KEY;
        $iv = $this->generateIV();
        $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($plain_text, 'aes-256-cbc', hex2bin($KEY), OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        return base64_encode($iv.$encrypted);
    }
```

```
    public function decrypt($encrypted){
        global $IV_LENGTH;
        global $KEY;
        $data = base64_decode($encrypted);
        $iv = substr($data, 0, $IV_LENGTH);
        $encryptedData = substr($data, $IV_LENGTH);
        return openssl_decrypt($encryptedData, 'aes-256-cbc', hex2bin($KEY), OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    }
```

```
    public function getKey(){
        $salt = random_bytes(256);
        $iterations = 999;
        $passphrase = 'orpheus';
        return hash_pbkdf2("sha512", $passphrase, $salt, $iterations, 64);
    }
```

```
    public function generateIV(){
        global $IV_LENGTH;
        return openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($IV_LENGTH);
    }
```

Encryption function for testing in JS (here, the KEY is the same as in the PHP code):

```
    import { Buffer } from 'buffer';
    import {KEY} from '../constants/Constants'
    import CryptoJS from 'react-native-crypto-js';

    const CryptoJSAesEncrypt = (text) => {
        let iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
        let encryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, KEY, {iv: iv});
        let encrypt = iv+encryptedData;
        return (Buffer.from(encrypt).toString('base64'));
    }
```

CryptoJSAesEncrypt, with input **textoo!** returns for example: **NGFjMjdkODMxNTNlMGYwZmM1ZDYyNTc1MTcwMjBkNDNVMkZzZEdWa1gxOWlUcXA4NXphaEx1VjdlbncwVEVxcm9vUENrSXlWUWZvPQ==**

```
    const CryptoJSAesDecrypt = (encrypted) => {
        let data = Buffer.from(encrypted, 'base64').toString('ascii');
        let iv = data.substring(0,16);
        let encryptedData = data.substring(16);
        let decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedData, KEY, {iv: iv});
        return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
    }
```

Edit:

I tested with the hex decoding included on the js functions

```
const CryptoJSAesEncrypt = (text) => {
    let iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
    let encryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(KEY).toString(), {iv: iv});
    let encrypt = iv+encryptedData;
    return (Buffer.from(encrypt).toString('base64'));
}
```

```
const CryptoJSAesDecrypt = (encrypted) => {
    let data = Buffer.from(encrypted, 'base64').toString('ascii');
    let iv = data.substring(0,16);
    let encryptedData = data.substring(16);
    let decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedData, CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(KEY).toString(), {iv: iv});
    return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}
```

Test:

```
    const text = 'YES!';
    const a = CryptoJSAesEncrypt(text);
    console.log('Text: ',text); //Text:  YES!
    console.log('Encryption: ',a); //Encryption:  MjAwYjdiMmNhODkwNDBiZDYxYTY2MTczNThiNjIwZDRVMkZzZEdWa1gxK0FwQ0F5d3VtMnc1ait4NGVVMkFVOFZ3OFczajZMcjJZPQ==
    console.log('Decryption: ', CryptoJSAesDecrypt(a)); //Decryption:
```

Decryption returns nothing.

Comment: Is KEY in the CryptoJS code a WordArray, how was this created? The corresponding code is missing (*...here, the KEY is the same as in the PHP code...* is not enough). Post a complete code including complete non-productive test data.

Comment: KEY is just string generated by the `getKey()`, it was created once:
`echo $c->getKey();`
Then I copied that value on a file of 'constants' in both the PHP endpoint and the ReacNative project. I stored it like this...
PHP: `$KEY = 'random string';`
ReactNative: `KEY = 'random string';`

Comment: Your key is hex encoded, i.e. consists of 64 hex digits. Why is it not hex decoded in the PHP code (`hex2bin()`)? Similarly, why is it not imported with the hex encoder in the CryptoJS code (`CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse()`)? Try this out.

Comment: If there are still problems, post the modified PHP and CryptoJS code and non-productive test data: key, plaintext, ciphertext of the PHP code.

Comment: How decoding hex makes a difference? I ask this because the decryption on PHP is working fine with the code above and without hex decoding.

Comment: AES-256 requires a 32 bytes key. Without hex decoding, your key is 64 bytes in size and therefore invalid. PHP silently truncates the key, CryptoJS does not do this, which is why you have to explicitly fix the key there. Thus, you have to fix the key in any case, so it is advisable to do this right from the start, namely to hex decode the hex encoded key. On top of this, the direct use of a hex encoded key (i.e. without hex decoding) is a vulnerability due to the reduced value range per byte.

Comment: When I use the hex decoding `CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(KEY)` it gives me `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined value to object` . Should I give it `toString()` conversion?

Comment: If `KEY` is a hex encoded key, it will work. Again, post test data so that it is clear what you are actually doing.

Comment: @Topaco, I have added the suggestions on the questions by editing it. Please check above.

Comment: I have asked you several times for complete non-productive test data. For some reason you don't post any. So I'm sorry, I can't help you.

Comment: Sorry. What is exactly complete non-productive test data?

Comment: I have already described this, see above: key, plaintext, ciphertext (at least) of the PHP code (so that a repro is possible). And non-productive should mean that you do not disclose any security-critical data, keys stc.

Comment: Added hex2bin() to my PHP functions in the question.
Test data below.
    `key = '7e800aa409e13b9760b7cb28d1a4aebb61c8595035dda735f9fea50133b0c96c'`
    `plaintext = 'Hello...'`
    `ciphertext = 'GpXdX8Rv346rerkpcIYSNLpiEFBG2ynsfyiaIRUw4Mw='`

Comment: Check this: https://snack.expo.dev/mtLKmqT4d

Comment: This works, thank you very much.